# How do you go to dashboard (start activity) after successful Login in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and Android Development and I want to go to my dashboard (another activity) when I successfully login, but when I try to, my app keeps crashing and I do not know why. I've searched for many solutions but they're years old so maybe that is why it is not working.

MainActivity Code:

```
package com.example.firstkotlin

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        if (currentUser != null) {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, dashboard::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        login()
    }

    private fun login() {
        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailLogin.text.toString())) {
                emailLogin.error = "Please enter registered email."
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordLogin.text.toString())) {
                passwordLogin.error = "Please enter password."
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailLogin.text.toString(), passwordLogin.text.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, dashboard::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@MainActivity,
                            "Login failed, please try again! ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                }

        }

        registerText.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, registration::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Dashboard Code:

```
package com.example.firstkotlin

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_dashboard.*

class dashboard : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    var  databaseReference : DatabaseReference? = null
    var database: FirebaseDatabase? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        databaseReference = database?.reference!!.child("profile")

    }

    private fun loadProfile(){

        val user = auth.currentUser
        val userreference = databaseReference?.child(user?.uid!!)
        
        userreference?.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                completeName.text = "User -- >" +snapshot.child("fullname").value.toString()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })

        logoutButton.setOnClickListener {
            auth.signOut()
            startActivity(Intent(this@dashboard, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE! Here's a stack trace:

```
03/24 17:12:49: Launching 'app' on No Devices.
Install successfully finished in 537 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.firstkotlin/com.example.firstkotlin.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 6798 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/ComponentDiscovery: Class com.google.firebase.dynamicloading.DynamicLoadingRegistrar is not an found.
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
W/ple.firstkotli: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ple.firstkotli: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firstkotlin, PID: 6798
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstkotlin/com.example.firstkotlin.dashboard}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.firstkotlin.dashboard.onCreate(dashboard.kt:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6798 SIG: 9
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: I'll look into it. In the meantime, is there a problem with my syntax? I'm still learning the language which makes me think it's a problem with my syntax.

Comment: I updated my question with the stack trace.

Comment: What is your android:theme value in dashboard's manifest?

Comment: I checked it and I noticed that they have different values with the Login Page. I changed it and it works!